# remove certain consecutive duplicates in a string?

Tags: python

I want to define a function that takes a string and a letter in that string and outputs a new string with the occurrences of the letter being once. For example

```
my_function("happy kitten","p")
'hapy kitten'
```

or

```
my_function("happykitten","t") 
'happykiten'
```

I've tried

```
def my_function(string, lett):
newString = ""
for char in string: #all characters
    for s in string: #character I'm testing
        if s == len(s) > 1: 
            newString+=lett # if there are multiple occurrences of s, replace with lett since its a single char anyway
        else:
            newString+=char #if not a duplicate, add next char to newString
    return newString #("happy kitten","p") returns 'ppppppppppp'
```

and

```
def my_function(string, lett):
newString = ""
for char in string: #all characters
    for s in string: #character I'm testing
        if s == s+1: 
            newString+=lett # if there are multiple occurrences of s, replace with lett since its a single char anyway
        else:
            newString+=char #if not a duplicate, add next char to newString
    return newString #TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

What't going wrong in my functions? Please no imports or built-in functions.

Comment: *"Please no imports or built-in functions."* - you will end up with an empty file...

Comment: Am i going about it the wrong way then if I want to do it the _primitive_ way without functions or imports?

Comment: Depends on you goal. If you aim to improve your knowledge of python and the quality of code you produce, then yes, ignoring the standard library would be a grave error. If however the goal of this exercise is to learn about algorithms and problem solving then it might be a good idea to do it the "primitive way" first.

Answer (score 4):

Well if you change your mind about the imports / built-in functions you can always do this:

```
from itertools import groupby

def my_function(s, c):
    return ''.join(c if a==c else ''.join(b) for a,b in groupby(s))
```

---

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> def my_function(s, c):
...     return ''.join(c if a==c else ''.join(b) for a,b in groupby(s))
... 
>>> my_function("happy kitten","p")
'hapy kitten'
>>> my_function("happykitten","t")
'happykiten'
```

Comment: It was requested that no imports would be used.

Comment: Hence the statement *"if you change your mind about the imports / built-in functions"*. I'm just trying to show the right way to do it.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but I just really need to practice not using imports and all that. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over the characters is inefficient and most likely the wrong thing to do. Sounds really much like a homework assignment on a freshman course. In real life you should look into regular expressions and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574509/python-remove-duplicate-chars-using-regex) seems to provide an elegant answer.

Your problem is that you assume that s+1 points to the next value in the iterator and that is not a valid assumption. What you will have to do is record the sighting and on the next iteration act accordingly.

We can still solve this for the matter of practice:

```
def strip_duplicate_letters(input, letter):
  output = ''
  last = False

  for c in input:
    if c == letter:
      if last:
        continue
      else:
        last = True
    else:
      last = False
    output += c

  return output
```

This is such an elemental thing that you will have to think it thoroughly over to make sure you understand. Then forget the example and reproduce yourself.

Another way is to enumerate the letters to make index numbers available:

```
for i, c in enumerate(input):
  if i > 0 and c == letter and input[i-1] == letter:
    continue
  output += c
```

In case `enumerate` is too much of a problem, you can use an integer as counter and increment it.

```
i = 0
for c in input:
  ....
  i += 1
  ...
```

Comment: These remove all occurrences of the letter instead of duplicates of consecutive letters. Thanks for your contribute though.

Comment: The two first ones work really well. The last one I did not test myself. However as you are clearly solving some school puzzle or something just like one, you will have to solve how to increment the counter yourself. This requires just the basic skills of programming and anyone can learn them with a little bit of work. I suggest you do it.