# Removing duplicate instances of a character using a regex expression using python

Tags: python, regex

This is what I tried:

```
(.)(?=.*\1)
```

This removes all instances of duplicates and leaves only the last instance, ie.

telnet -> lnet

I want this result:

telnet -> teln

How do I do this? I tried looking behind, but that only accepts a fixed length as far as I know.

Need to find a REGEX for this. I know other methods to achieve this without regex

Comment: "Need to find a REGEX for this." Really? Why?

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible. I think it's possible in .NET, but in python, could not think of a regex. The straightforward approach is simple enough, this is out of curiosity.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Would you be so kind as to unmark my question as a duplicate, or even better, link it to a more appropriate duplicate if it exists.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4575626/2617068), there's no single regex operation to do this.

Comment: It is possible with PyPi regex module.

Answer (score 1):

Pure regex solution is not possible.You can try with callback function though.

```
z=[]
def fun(matchobj):
    if matchobj.group(1) in z or matchobj.group(2) in z:
        return ''
    else:
        if matchobj.group(1):
             z.append(matchobj.group(1))
        else:
             z.append(matchobj.group(2))
        return z[-1]



x="telnet"
print re.sub(r"(.)(?=.*\1)|(.)", fun, x)
```

Answer (score 1):

a little 'hack' would be ... to reverse the string before and after the lookahead

```
import re

expr = r'telnetrer'[::-1]
pr = re.sub(r'(.)(?=.*\1)', r'', expr)[::-1]

print(pr)
```

Output

```
>>> telnr
```