# Removing neighboring duplicates in list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, element

I convert string `a` to a list and I want the loop to create ‍`tabb = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']`

```
a = aaabbbbcccaaa

taba = list(a)
tabb = []

for i in taba:
    for j in range(len(tabb)):
        if not i[j] == i[j-1]:
            tabb.append(i[j])

print (tabb)
```

But apparently my solution `gives tabb = []`

Do You have any better and simple ideas to make it work?

Comment: @alex OP wants the second `'a'` in this example. The proposed duplicate is wrong in this case.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis not sure it's incorrect... the answers cover various approaches for unique characters for an entire string and also unique consecutive characters. I'm open to another more specific duplicate if you have one to mind?

Comment: @JonClements There is one good one but it is [regex specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574509/remove-duplicate-chars-using-regex). There has to be one though.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis thought I also saw a groupby?

Comment: @JonClements [this one maybe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460855/python-how-to-remove-duplicates-only-if-consecutive-in-a-string/11498830)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis that's great. Good find - thank you.

Answer (score 5):

[groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) is your ally:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = 'aaabbbbcccaaa'

res = [x for x, _ in groupby(a)]
print(res)  # -> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```

---

The solution without any libraries (the one you were trying to arrive at) would be:

```
res = [a[0]]

for i, c in enumerate(a[1:]):
    if c != a[i]:
        res.append(c)
```

which has the same outcome of course.

Comment: Thank you, it worked flawlessly!
BTW I'm trying to make reverse function and I almost made it work but it seems that it can't reach the first element of array: goo.gl/3cHkWN ( link to code in google docs)   ///      If input = AAABBBBCAAAaaDD, string = A3B4CA3a2D2 decompressed should be AAABBBBAAAaaDD
 but is BBBBAAAaaDD.
 Can You see why the loop can't see taba[2-1]?

Comment: post this as a separate question. It is beneficial for the community

Comment: also note that the fact that you do not have a `1` after the `'C'` makes it much more complicated than it has to be. If you have control over the format of the input string, please add it.