# How to use Regular Expression to remove repeated characters Python

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a list of unique values from a column df

```
aa                2     
aaa               10    
aaaa              14    
aaaaa             2     
aaaaaa            1     
aableasing        25    
yy                1     
yyy               6        
überimexcars      1     
üüberimexcars     1     
üüüüüüüüü         2
```

The aim is to 'clean' the data by grouping on Name.

Thus:

- aa = aaa = aaaa
- ü = üüü = üüüüüü
- ...

The desired output would be as shown below

```
a                 29      
aableasing        25    
y                 7           
überimexcars      2  
üüüüüüüüü         2
```

I was thinking of something like

```
df['name'] = df['name'].astype(str).str.replace('aaa', 'a')
```

However, I would have to do it for each letter. Furthermore, that's not really an efficient of doing the thing.

Using Regular Expression in this case might be a better option?

Thanks anyone who is helping!

Comment: Is it something you are looking for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574509/remove-duplicate-chars-using-regex)?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks, it's doing the job. df['name'] = df['name'].astype(str).str.replace(r'([a-z])\1+', r'\1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
df['name']=df['name'].replace(r"^(.)\1*$", r"\1", regex=True)
```

Some explanation:

It will try to match the whole cell (from the beginning - `^` , till the end - `$`) to any character `(.)` which then is repeated 0, or more times (reference to first group, denoted by square brackets) - `\1*` and all this will be replaced (if it's matched only) with this first group `\1`.

Answer (score 0):

if t contains a string, e.g. 'aaaaa', try the following:

```
t.join(sorted(set(t), key=t.index))
```

you'll get 'a'.

Now run this on your dataframe and group